# How to Read a TCP port/Socket in NodeJS? There's no "read" method

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm supposed to communicate with a controller, which has a port configured to send status data. I should read on port 2424 of a specific IP, with NodeJS.
I've tried all I could, and nothing is read.
Here's are my perplexities:
* i receive no "connect" event- could this be because the interface, implemented at controller level, is very simplistic? Or no connection is established
* no "read" method in nodejs's socket- just an on('data') which never received anything.

I mention that I did no listen, since my app is a client doesn't take in any connections, just connects to a service to receive data

My code is this:

```
var host = 'xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt';
var port = 2424;
var client = net.connect({port:port, host:host}, function() {
    log.logOut(ModName, '[checkPortaRack] Client connected.');
});

client.setTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT * 1000);

client
    .on('timeout', function() {
    client.destroy();
    callback(new Error("No data received. So device '"+dev.name+"' in error"));
})
.on('connect', function() {
    log.logOut(ModName, '[checkPortaRack] Connected...');
})
.on('data', function(chunk) {
    data += chunk;
    console.log(data.toString());
    log.logOut(ModName, 'Got data...');
    client.destroy();
})
.on('end', function() {
    data = data.toString().replace('\u0000',"");
    log.logOut(ModName, 'Data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('client disconnected');
})
.on('error', function(e) {
    status.deviceDown = true;
    log.logOut(ModName, "[checkPortaRack][Device Error]["+dev.name+"] ERROR Getting data from device: " + e.message);
    callback(new Error("Error while receiving data. So device '"+dev.name+"' in error"));
});
```

The people in charge sent this C# code, which they say works like a charm:

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("catch");
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
                break;
            }

            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```

So, question is: how can I read this ip/port, using node's socket, without a "read" method and without a "connect" event being sent?

Thanks a lot,
Catalin

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: Also, do you get any events at all?

Comment: @mscdex: using node v0.8.21

Comment: @mscdex: not sure how to check whether I receive any messages: since I don't receive "connect", all others can't really happen. I do use the same server for some datagram protocol, and I receive all the packages. Tcp however, no luck so far.

Comment: You can try using node v0.10.26 (latest v0.10 version) and see if that helps any, but if you're absolutely sure it's really supposed to be TCP and not UDP or something else, then I do not know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your node code generally looks ok.

You could try changing

```
var client = net.connect({port:port, host:host}, function() {
    log.logOut(ModName, '[checkPortaRack] Client connected.');
});
```

to

```
var client = new net.Socket();
```

and then add this to the bottom of your code:

```
client.connect(port, host);
```

Comment: I tried all ways, also the way you suggest. Also tried var client = net.createConnection(port, host, function() { ... });